# Should I use a server kernel when making a ssh server?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-server, energy-saving

I am setting up my desktop as an ssh server and leaving it at home while I travel and connect with a laptop.

Will the server kernel provide any advantages for such a simple use as this? Like energy saving or less cpu cycles?

ubuntu server and client

Comment: I'll bet the chief difference between them is the scheduler configuration.  The client kernel is likely tuned for interactive (i.e. desktop) use (preventing things from making the desktop freeze) whereas the server kernel is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the average home server, there's unlikely to be a massive difference - the differences between the server and standard kernel are primarily for big iron systems.